# Entry and Exit of people in pizza delivery shop

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid, time

<sup>*Similar problem at: https://brainly.in/question/38234304*</sup>

Five people went to a pizza delivery shop at different times on a Sunday morning.

They spent exactly 15 mins, 16 mins, 20 mins, 25 mins and 35 mins (in some order) in the shop.

Not more than two people were in the shop at the same time.

The following information is known:

1. Mr. Nayak entered at 10:47.
2. Mr. Shetty and Mr. Nayak were both together in the shop for exactly 8 mins.
3. The person who came 44 mins after Mr. Das entered, spent 25 mins in the shop.
4. Mr. Kamat complained that he was made to wait too long.
   Mr. Shetty entered 8 mins after Mr. Chitale did and left 23 mins after the latter left.
5. The last person left at 11:27

Who spent exactly 25 minutes in the shop?

Comment: Please give proper attribution. Looks like its picked up from [here](https://brainly.in/question/38234304)

Comment: That site doesn't have any solution given

Comment: It may not, but you still should provide proper attribution when writing your puzzles

Answer (score 1):

Premise 4 tells us three names, and

> that Shetty spent 35 minutes, and Chitale 20 minutes.

Premise 1 and 2 combine to tell us which minutes, and construct a timeline

> Chitale enter 10:12, Shetty enter 10:20, Chitale leave 10:32, Nayak enter 10:47, Shetty leave 10:55

And then premise 3 and 5 give us the solution

> Das latest entry at 10:18, 69 minutes before 11:27, but 10:18 doesn't give him time to leave before Shetty enters. Nayak cannot remain in the store until 11:27, as no timeframe is long enough, so Kamat must. This means that Nayak must have been in the store for 25 minutes.